# Laravel inserting data in one to many tables

Tags: php, laravel, backend

Good morning developers, iam working on ecommerce project using laravel and angular
in laravel i made two tables ( brands - products ) and i need the brand has many products
so i added this function to the Product model

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

and i added this function to Brand model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

the first question is how i could handle the relation in the products table migration file, is this right or there is better way?

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
$table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
```

the second questions is should i define the brand_id in the $fillable products property or not

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'brand_id', 'display', 'ram', 'storage', 'rear_cam', 'front_cam', 'img', 'price'];
```

the third question is how to handle the store product function and note iam using api calls between angular and laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100', 'display' => 'required|string|max:100', 'ram' => 'required|string|max:100', 'img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png',
        'storage' => 'required|string|max:100', 'rear_cam' => 'required|string|max:200', 'front_cam' => 'required|string|max:200',
        'price' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $img = $request->file('img');
    $ext = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $name = 'product-' . uniqid() . ".$ext";
    $img->move(public_path('uploads/books/'), $name);

    $name = $request->name;
    $brand_id = $request->brand_id;
    $display = $request->display;
    $ram = $request->ram;
    $storage = $request->storage;
    $rear_cam = $request->rear_cam;
    $front_cam = $request->front_cam;
    $price = $request->price;
    $product = Product::create(['name' => $name, 'brand_id' => $brand_id, 'display' => $display, 'img' => $name, 'ram' => $ram, 'storage' => $storage, 'rear_cam' => $rear_cam, 'front_cam' => $front_cam, 'price' => $price]);

    $product->brand()->sync($request->brand_id);

    $success = 'Product created successfully';

    return response()->json($success);
}
```

when iam trying to store a product it says there is error with the sync function, what function should i use instead of it

Comment: you already have a 'brand_id' column, so you don't have to sync

Comment: First, try divide your question to smaller unit and create question separately, Secondly, put here any error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need it to sync, In many-to-many relationships require an additional table called pivot table where you Managing Many-to-Many Relationships using attach-detach-sync method but in case you havnt situation like this.
Undo this Line

```
    $product->brand()->sync($request->brand_id);
```

After Product created successfully. If you simply called products function to Brand model. You will seeing last created product are there.
Ex:-

```
Brand::with('products')->find($brand_id)
```

Thanks

Comment: can i ask you another question pls?
what is the line i use in the delete function that when i delete the brand it deletes the whole products with this brand

Comment: $brand->products()->delete();

Comment: then $brand->delete();

Comment: Hope this will  make sense

Comment: yeah it's perfect thanks a lot, i wish you a good day

Comment: Thanks @OsamaAmr If this helpful for you, please vote up for me

Answer (score 0):

> the first question is how i could handle the relation in the products table migration file, is this right or there is better way?

It is indeed the good way to handle this.

> the second questions is should i define the brand_id in the $fillable products property or not

It all depends on your use case. Typically you only define the attributes the user can modify at will, like his name. The concept of `fillable` is here to  protect you from mass assignment.

For instance:

- if I change the name attribute of a check box from `accept_newsletter` to `is_admin`
- and if a column named `is_admin` exists
- and if `is_admin` is in the `fillable` attributes
- and you do something like that: `$user->update($request->all());`

Then I could potentially become an admin.

However, if `is_admin` isn't in the `fillable` attributes, you must explicitly do something like: `$user->is_admin = $request->is_admin`. Which is much more unlinkely to happen involuntarily.

In your case, the person who will add/edit a product will probably be an admin anyway so you can add `brand_id` to the `fillable` attributes.

For your third question, since you are using a `hasMany` relationship on the `Brand` model and a `belongsTo` in the `Product` model, all you have to do is `$product->brand()->associate($request->brand_id);`.

But keep in mind that here:

```php
product = Product::create(['name' => $name, 'brand_id' => $brand_id, 'display' => $display, 'img' => $name, 'ram' => $ram, 'storage' => $storage, 'rear_cam' => $rear_cam, 'front_cam' => $front_cam, 'price' => $price]);
```

You already assign the `brand_id` to the product you are creating (it'll only work if you added `brand_id` to the fillable attributes). Think of the `fillable` attributes as "attributes that can be assigned within an array".